# ds4windows not working anymore after scptoolkit install

Tags: ps4, controllers, windows-10

i was using ps4 controller on my win10 pc with ds4windows, it was workign like a charm.

after installing scptoolkit to try installing some ps3 controller, my ps4 controller via Bluetooth does not work anymore.

I fully uninstalled scp toolkit (forums.vigem.org/topic/250/scptoolkit-removal-guide). I reinstalled ds4windows (the good one ryochan7.github.io/ds4windows-site),

using usb cable it works,

using bluetooth the controller is pairing, it is showing up in ds4windows and the gamepad test is working (html5gamepad.com)

**But** if i go in windows "game controllers" panel a wireless controller entry is showing up, if i test using properties button no input is detected, if I try to play the controller are not working
what should i do? I tried everything

Answer (score 1):

All the instruction were found [in this forum](https://forums.vigem.org/topic/250/scptoolkit-removal-guide). All credits goes to the author of the post.

I'm writing them in case the link is not available anymore, but you should check it.

ScpToolkit can be tricky to be removed.

Run CMD with admin privilege and run:

```
taskkill /F /IM ScpServer.exe
taskkill /F /IM ScpMonitor.exe
taskkill /F /IM ScpTrayApp.exe
```

Then run:

```
sc stop Ds3Service
sc delete Ds3Service
```

Then, you'll have to remove the drivers installed by SCP. You can install [DriverStore Explorer](https://github.com/lostindark/DriverStoreExplorer/releases/tag/v0.10.58) to do so.

Now we need to instruct Windows to revert the devices to their default drivers. Open Device Manager and look for a node titled libusbK USB Devices:
You'll find 2 devices, PLAYSTATION(R) 3 Controller and CSR8510 A10 (The bluetooth hostn may be different for you), just uninstall the drivers. Note that the sections and device names may be different in your case.

Also, apparently a copy of the driver can still remain in memory and therefore won't be deleted. Re-plug all devices and check if they are still running under the SCP drivers. Uninstall again and re-plug again until it's not appearing again.

And then you can remove scp install directory.

Comment: sadly i alreay did that "I fully uninstalled scp toolkit."

Comment: Don't run taskkill before stopping the service. Run sc stop, then taskkilll and then sc delete.